# generalisations of the modular group

Tags: group-theory, modular-group

I read about how Hecke groups are a particular generalisation of the modular group, generalising one of the generators of the modular group to $z\mapsto z + \lambda$. Have people studied generalisations of the other generator of the modular group, perhaps generalising to $z \mapsto \dfrac{-1}{z^n}$  ?

Comment: What is your proposed inverse of $z \mapsto \dfrac{-1}{z^n}$?

Comment: It would be $z \mapsto \sqrt[n]{\dfrac{-1}{z}}$, but the roots in the upper-half plane would all have to be identified.